# Redmine on RHEL 6 not sending emails - AUTH mechanism LOGIN not available

Tags: email, sendmail, redmine, rhel6

I have RHEL6 with installed Redmine 2.6. While trying to set up sending emails I got the error :

```
504 5.3.3 AUTH mechanism LOGIN not available
```

More than all, while changing the password of an account, the email came to me successfully. Hmm...

So i tried googling that trouble but that gave me no resolved issues. Please, help me to understand how to find out what is wrong. That is important !